# What do the lyrics of "2Wicky" by Hooverphonic refer to?

Tags: music, reference, hooverphonic

The [lyrics to the song "2Wicky"](https://genius.com/Hooverphonic-2-wicky-lyrics) by the band Hooverphonic seems to contain a couple of scifi references.

> **Prophet-60091
>
>   This is the flight number of our galactic sun**
>   Prophet-60091
>   Before we start you should know that you're not the only one
>   Who can hurt me
>
> **SH10151
>
>   This is the serial number of our orbital gun**
>   SH10151
>   You better be sure before you leave me for another one
>
> <sub>"2Wicky" by Hooverphonic *(emphasis added)*</sub>

What do these refer to and are they referenced in/from another science fiction work?

Comment: I've seen some conflicting ideas here; https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/2990/ but none seem conclusive. I'm not looking for speculation, but actual evidence/proof

Comment: @user14111 The only difference between obscure, meaningless phrases like "Prophet-60091" and "Klaatu barada nikto" is whether someone came through with an answer to the question, so I think it's fair to leave it open and see if anyone comes up with a sci-fi reference.

Comment: @Valorum based on your logic you are opening up this forum to every song lyric in every song that could conceivably be a sci-fi term - and I think that would be a mistake, as sometimes a word is just a word that sounds good in a song.  OTOH you could convince me otherwise if you can show a progression of such lyrics in this band's material potentially indicating a definite sci-fi inspired *theme*.  EG Analyzing the lyrics of "Flash" by Queen definitely would belong here, or the "Science Fiction/Double Feature" song from the Rocky Horror Show.  Both of which have direct links to Sci-Fi

Comment: @PeterM I've found articles describing the lyrics of the main writer of the band as "science fiction inspired".

Comment: @SQB Well that's background information that fits in to my "OTOH" clause :D.  But with an obscure (to me) band that sort of information needs to be explicit.

Comment: @PeterM - Orbital guns do exist outside of scifi (for welding, apparently) but it seems unlikely that that's what she's talking about.

Comment: @Valorum I did the google and found a random upload of the song so I could at least hear part of it.  I also found a comment that suggested that the band likes English sounding wordplay.  See the comments to https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/2990/

Comment: The Prophet-600 is a digitally controlled analog synthesizer.  It has (among other things)  100 preset sounds, selected using a two digit number from 00 to 99.  [The manual](https://encyclotronic.com/uploads/b7f591e0ffe166da9dd383e212fe79e0.pdf) says 51 is "digital brass" and 91 is "filter funk."  They might have used those sounds in the song, and used the sound codes to extend the model numbers of the synthesizers to make the text flow better.

Comment: The SH-101 doesn't have presets.  [The manual](http://cdn.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/SH-101_OM.pdf) has a list of named sounds, but only goes to like 39.  So, if the 2 digit extensions come from sound codes then they're both from the Prophet-600.

Comment: Purely speculation, but reasonable since they clearly used the names of synthesizers in the song.

Comment: The Prophet-600 has a two digit red LED display that shows the selected preset - or the loaded custom program number.  Custom programs are also numbered 00 to 99, but there's an additional lighted decimal point in the display to indicate a custom program.

Comment: For the rest, it seems to use science fiction inspired terms to pep up a rather mundane song about a woman (who has more than one boyfriend, and is involved in picking up another) creepily warning the new guy not to cheat on her or leave her.

Comment: The one thing that came to mind when I heard this in the 00's was a typical Iain M. Banks story with the female protagonist from the Culture having both a few lovers and a few orbiting direct delivery force packages at her disposal. Which she both uses and no regrets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [answer of Adam](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/213440/15363) seems to be correct, as confirmed by the comment of niefpaarschoenen.
I had a quick look at the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkBwp1qFr68&t) of that Belpop episode and found some relevant parts at 4:20-5:30.

> 4:20 |
> Raymond Geerts: Goh, ik weet nog, op een dag, Alex belde mij en zei "Ja man, ik heb hier een ongelooflijke sample gevonden en je moet eens afkomen, want ik ben er een nummmer mee aan het maken."
>
> 4:30 |
> RG: Dat was echt een wonderbaarlijk moment. Ongelooflijk.
>
> 4:35 | [op beeld: 1969 Isaac Hayes - Walk on By] [muziek]
>
> 4:37 |
> Alex Callier: Het was een Isaac Hayes nummer, maar het was een cover van [onverstaanbaar], het was Walk on By.
>
> [muziek]
>
> 4:47 |
> AC: En wij hebben dat gesampled *at* the intro naar Walk on By van Isaac Hayes.
>
> [muziek]
>
> 4:58 |
> Esther Lybeert: Die sample kwam en die tekst onstond door die synthesizer die daar stond. De woorden 'Prophet 60091, SH10151', dat waren gewoon de bakken die daar stonden. Toen is dat zowat onstaan, eigenlijk.
>
> 5:17 | [op beeld: 1995 Hoover - 2Wicky] [muziek]

Or (loosely) translated to English:

> 4:20 |
> Raymond Geerts: Well, I still remember, one day Alex called me and said "Dude, I've found an incredible sample, you have to come over, because I'm making as song with it."
>
> 4:30 |
> RG: That was truly a wonderful moment. Unbelievable.
>
> 4:35 | [on screen: 1969 Isaac Hayes - Walk on By] [music]
>
> 4:37 |
> Alex Callier: It was an Isaac Hayes song, but it was a cover from [did not understand], it was Walk on By.
>
> [music]
>
> 4:47 |
> AC: And we sampled that song at the intro to Walk on By of Isaac Hayes.
>
> [music]
>
> 4:58 |
> Esther Lybeert: **That sample arrived and the lyrics originated by the synthesizer that was standing there. The words 'Prophet 60091, SH10151', they were simply those boxes that were standing there. That's how it started, basically.**
>
> 5:17 | [on screen: 1995 Hoover - 2Wicky] [music]

About those 'boxes': from what she says, to me it's ambiguous whether she's talking about the actual synthesizer, or about cardboard boxes (as original packaging for the synthesizer), or about sturdy cases to move the synthesizer (and/or other material) around to and from gigs.

The interviews then continue about how they were able to bring the song to a broad audience and how psychedelic the music video of their television performance of this song was.
I didn't watch the video after that, so I don't know if they say anything else about the lyrics of this song.

Comment: Great work. As you can imagine, my Dutch is somewhat lacking.

Comment: Now we just need the synthesiser company to start producing movies based on those boxes.

Comment: @Valorum - I'm kind of wondering why you never accepted the answer, especially as you gave it a nice bonus...  oversight?

Comment: @Basya - That's my bad

Comment: And fixed now, I see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The answer you are looking for, in-part anyway, is that the 2 codes are the names of electronic Synthesizers from the early 1980s.
Sequential Circuits (USA) manufactured the Prophet 600
 and Roland (Japan) manufactured the SH-101 (I used to own a Roland SH-101 - until I foolishly sold it to part-pay for a holiday!!
My guess is that both keyboards may have been used also in the actual music of the song, but I don't have proof.
The additional numbers after both (91 and 51) may have no connection other than to complete the lyric so that it works best for the song.
Amazing song and even more amazing band.

Comment: I've seen this theory [advanced on the Internet](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/2990/) (on numerous occasions) per [my comment above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204263/what-do-the-lyrics-of-2wicky-by-hooverphonic-refer-to/213440#comment558165_204263). My concern is that neither actually fit the lyrics. There was no Prophet-600***91***, nor did the Roland have a SH101***51*** code. Also, why would the band reference either of these numbers?

Comment: This is indeed correct. It is confirmed in an episode of Belpop on the band.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen - This (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkBwp1qFr68&t)??? I don't speak Dutch but if you can translate the relevant bits and write an answer, you'll earn yourself a fat bounty.